# If a question is marked "too broad" because I am still new to the topic, does that mean I should not have asked the question?

Tags: support, needs-more-focus

Today I asked a question about Python because I'm a newbie in it and I got my question marked as "too broad."

My question was this:

> I have Python program which contains some .py files.
>
> I want to release it for public but I want to add a auto updater for
>   it that it downloads new .py files and replaces it the existing ones
>   because my program is in beta and it is not completed yet.
>
> I don't have problem with hosting it or with the libraries requered to
>   do this but my question is this: How can I write a updater in Python?
>
> I tried searching Google for a long time but I couldn't find anything
>   related to it.

What I was saying in the question is that I don't even know how to download a file in Python, so how can I write such a program like this?

If I don't know how to do something in Python and the question has multiple answers, does that mean I shouldn't ask?

Comment: Note that downvotes on meta are simply means to show whether users agree or disagree with something. Getting downvotes will not give you any penalities here (unlike the main side).

Comment: Honestly. some of the old users are not kind  to the new users. They don't even respect new users. However, it is one big place where I can learn a lot about how programming works.

Comment: "Respect" isn't the thing you're not getting here.  You're definitely getting that.  What *we're* stating is that you're not exactly being respectful of the community in that your question is *overly broad*.  If you don't know the basics, why do you think that we can show them to you in such a short time?

Comment: I mean the way they speak to the new users. I have posted a question, maybe it sounds too simple for the expert here. And he/she commented "hahaha" below my post. It sounds rude ! However, his/her comment get deleted immediately. :)

Comment: @Makoto I think you answered to the wrong person :)

Comment: I'm not asking how to create software

Comment: @Makoto Hoo is not the OP, which handle is Ali SH.

Comment: Oops.  Well, don't I feel embarrassed... I'll just clean up after myself and show myself out then.

Comment: @Makoto your points are still valid, regardless of who they were directed to. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you don’t know how to do even basic things in Python, then it’s really difficult for us to answer the question without having to explain even basic things. And we simply cannot explain the whole language and its concepts just like that.

We can help you with individual problems you face when working on this, but we’re not here to teach you how to use a language.

There are many resources that will teach you how to solve problems in Python, how to perform certain tasks. For example, you can start [here](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) and learn the language.

Then, to solve your actual program, you should figure out how to split the problem up into subproblems. For example, for your auto updater, you could split it up into figuring out whether a new version exists on your server, downloading the new version files, replacing the existing installation with the new files, and finally (maybe) restarting the application with the new files. Each of those is a new simpler problem which you should analyze and think about how you could solve it.

If you run into concrete problems, then you are welcome to come here and ask for help, but if your problem is essentially the whole problem and you have no idea how to start, then a question asking for a solution is simply too broad.

Since you say, you don’t know how to download a file in Python, if you really don’t know how to start, then google for that. E.g. googling for “download file python” gives the following results:

- [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)
- [Basic http file downloading and saving to disk in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python)

Those are a good start. If you build upon that knowledge, you should be able to get further. And if at some point you run into a problem, figure out what exactly the problem is, the *subproblem*. And then you can search for that subproblem again and in case you don’t any existing help, you can ask and tell us what you have tried and how that didn’t work out.

Comment: thanks for coming here and answering to me.i know you are a proffesional in python,Even you helped **a lot** in my question,but before you have mentioned it i searched for downloding file in python, i got answer for that but for cheking newer version i got **nothing** in google,not even 1 simple tip in google,and i got nothing in restarting program in python, so i decided to ask,now, i dont know these two i mentioned, if i want to ask what should i exactly include,i include what ever you say to get my answer because i am in hurry and i got to complete it as soon as possible.thanks.

Comment: That’s what I meant with you should analyze and think about those subproblems. Let’ take that newer version recognition as another example: In order to be able to identify a newer version, you first need to have actually versioning of your files. Now you could use source code hosts like GitHub which already give you versioning as part of the version control software, but you could also run your own thing completely. Let’s just use simple numbers for now. So you need a way to get the version number you have locally, and you need to have the most current version number somewhere online. This […]

Comment: […] can be as simple as storing a text file next to your python files, and serving a text file on some webserver. So all you would need to do at the beginning is read the local version number, get the version number from your webserver and compare those. If the number on the webserver is greater than your local one, you need to run the update.

Comment: ,Thanks,i got the algorithm but i don't know how to connect to github or ... , so i decide to leave this program because i cant even ask my question and if i do i get lots of vote downs.like my question above,(-8).thanks for your help

Comment: Well, you keep running into newer and smaller things you don’t know how to solve. That’s usually a good thing because smaller problems are easier to solve, and then it’s just a matter of composing your solutions to solve the bigger problem. As for asking problems, you should definitely put some more work into them. Include what you have already tried, your attempted solutions, why it didn’t work, and how you tried to solve the problem. That way, people understand what you were already doing, and especially see that you already tried to do something instead of just coming here to ask for code.